# Visual Studio 2015 / MVC app stuck on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have the oddest bug.

I have an MVC app which has been in development for over a year and works pretty much flawlessly. I've been developing on Windows 8 / VS 2013, but recently upgraded to Win 10 / VS 2015

Today I performed a `POST` which brought up an expected result page on my browser (MS Edge). However, now every page on the site displays this same results page. This is not an app error. I can set breakpoints on my controllers and views and see that they are being executed / rendered. However when the browser refreshes, this out of date results page shows.

I have tried a different browser, tried restarting Visual Studio, IIS, and browsers. The only thing I've yet to do is restart windows itself.

When I rebuild the app and relaunch, I am prompted to log in - this is the only page I see other than the results page.

I'm reporting this to MS as a VS2015 bug but I wanted to hear if anyone else had the same issue

## UPDATE:

This bug has now survived browser cache clearing and a system reboot

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly would we reproduce this? Sure you didn't mess up anything?

Comment: yeah there's no way to reproduce. posting here was a shot in the dark. And I'm 100% positive. I'll come back and reply with whatever MS comes up with

Comment: They would require something more than 'it doesn't work' too.

Comment: that's the problem when Microsoft comes out with a new ver of their operating system.. they don't test it and it's never good until the 2nd 3rd or 4th release.. roll it back to your previous OS version ..

Comment: Is your browser caching anything? It sounds like your browser is caching the data.

Comment: @Method they test each release much more than we test all versions of all our products all together in all our life. Just number of public beta testers is huge. Is it an operating system a complex thing? Sure. What we think it's their bug...is in reality our bug? Most times...

Comment: A shot in the dark...but what happens if you try Chrome? I

Comment: Have you tried adding cache control headers to each response?

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Browser link saved the content of that response page back to my project, overwriting my `_Layout.cshtml` page.

I must have clicked "save changes" on the browser link overlay bar by accident. Since it was an MVC app it just wrote this content back to the top controller, the layout or master page. Each Controller Action was processing, each View was rendering, but the layout file had static content instead of showing the View in question.